# Get instagram image link automatic

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

I'm currently using this script, to get the latest 6 images from my instagram feed.

```
var token = 'MY_TOKEN',
        num_photos = 6, // maximum 20
        container = document.getElementById('rudr_instafeed'), // it is our <ul id="rudr_instafeed">
        scrElement = document.createElement('script');

    window.mishaProcessResult = function (data) {
        for (x in data.data) {
            container.innerHTML += '<li><a href="IMAGE LINK TO INSTAGRAM"><img id="Test" src="' + data.data[x].images.low_resolution.url + '"></a></li>';
        }
    }

    scrElement.setAttribute('src', 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=' + token + '&count=' + num_photos + '&callback=mishaProcessResult');
    document.body.appendChild(scrElement);
```

But i was wondering, if i can change my `IMAGE LINK TO INSTAGRAM` in my href, to get the image link, so it would look like this: instagram.com/p/IMAGE_ID

I've tried doing `href="instagram.com/p/ '+ data.data[x]'"` but that didn't work.

Here is what data brings. I need that link, to be replaced at my `IMAGE LINK TO INSTAGRAM`
[image]

Comment: href="h t t p s : / / instagram.com/p/ '+ data.data[x] +" ' or show us what data brings to us. (I would add target="_blank" to the href to open in a new tab the image

Comment: Roy, the data.data[x] makes the url looks like this: instagram.com/p/%20[object%20Object]

Comment: Again, please, share what **data** brings us

Comment: data.data[x]['id'] maybe?

Comment: I've tried adding .image.url and it just set my value to undefied.

Comment: Try data.data[x]['id']... or make a **console.log(data)** to see what it brings us...

Comment: Roy Updatede my question with image of data :)

Comment: Found the answere. data.data[x].link and it's working fine :)

Comment: Perfect, good luck coding!